# Why is this map closed?

Tags: general-topology

I've encountered with this question during reading J.M.Lee's book:

Define an equivalence relation on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$:
$(x,y)\sim(x',y')$  iff  $(x',y')=(x+n,(-1)^{n}y) $   for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$

$E:= \mathbb{R}^{2}/\sim$ denote the quotient space, $q:\mathbb{R}^{2}\to E$  be the quotient map.

$S=[0,1]\times\mathbb{R}\subset\mathbb{R}^{2}$  denote the strip,here comes the question:why is the restriction of $q$ to $S$ a closed map?

I've tried to chase the definition of quotient topology but gained nothing,is there something I miss?

Comment: The map q itself is closed.

Comment: I don't think $q$ is closed. The image of $\{(n+1/n,0)\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$ is not closed.

Comment: @StefanHamcke It is. You should have excluded $n = 1$ ;)

Comment: @DanielFischer: My $\Bbb N$ starts at $2$ ;-)

Comment: You're an old Greek, @Stefan?

Comment: Did the Greeks start counting at $2$ ? @DanielFischer

Comment: @Stefan Not that, but $1$ wasn't considered a number, $2$ was the smallest number. (Hence, for Euclid, the question whether $1$ was a prime didn't arise. Only numbers were primes.)

Comment: @Daniel: $1$ wasn't considered a number ? Really? Didn't know that.

Comment: @StefanHamcke VII. Buch, Definitionen "1. __Einheit__ ist das, wonach jedes Ding eines genannt wird. 2. __Zahl__ ist die aus Einheiten zusammengesetzte Menge. 13. __Zusammengesetzt__ ist eine Zahl, die sich durch irgendeine (andere) Zahl messen läßt." Anmerkung zu VII Def. 2: "$1$ ist für die Alten keine Zahl; so ist Euklid vielfach zur Unterscheidung mehrerer Fälle gezwungen, wo weitere Fassung des Zahlbegriffs dies überflüssig gemacht hätte."

Comment: Dann müsste man noch "messen einer Zahl" definieren. @DanielFischer:

Comment: Ist auch irgendwo definiert, @Stefan. Kuck' ich jetzt aber nicht nach.

Comment: Ist auch nicht so wichtig @DanielFischer. Wär auch etwas off-topic, und der OP wird über jeden comment notified. Weswegen waren wir noch mal hier? Achja: $$\{n+1/(n+2)\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$$ does not have a closed image.

Comment: $\{ (n + 1/(n+2),0) \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, @Stefan. Let's be pedantic.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thanks. Very well spotted :-)

Answer (score 1):

Denote by $q'$ the restriction of $q$ to $S$. This is a surjective map $q':S\to E$. If a subset $C$ of $S$ is closed, then its saturation $D$ is closed, too. It suffices to show that $D_n:=D\cap S_n$ is closed, where $S_n$ is the string $[n,n+1]\times\Bbb R$, since $D$ is a locally finite union of those sets.

Let $r$ be the homeomorphisms which sends $(x,y)$ to $(x,-y)$

Start with $D_0$: Since $C$ is closed, so are $C\cap(\{0\}×\Bbb R)$ and 
$C∩(\{1\}×\Bbb R)$. The saturation $D_0$ in $S_0$ is 
$$D_0=C\cup r[C∩(\{0,1\}×\Bbb R)]$$
which is closed.
Now assume by induction, that $D_n$ is closed. Since the generating relation is 
$(x,y)\simeq (x\pm1,-y)$,
$D_{n+1}$ is obtained by taking $r[D_n+(1,0)]$, which is obviously closed.
So $D=\bigcup D_n$ is closed, and so is $q'(C)=q(D)$